# How can I start to create my own code generator to produce Entity objects?

Tags: c#, entity, generator

I am analyzing a system in c# that has 2 libraries: Business Layer and Data layer Access.

Business library has:

```
    1 BaseManager.cs class
    Several Managers (ClientManager.cs, ContactManager.cs, etc).

    1 BaseEntity.cs class
    Several Entities(Client.cs, Contact.cs, etc)

    1 NotifyPropertyChange.cs  class
```

The data access layer has:

```
    1 BaseData.cs class
    Several data objects (ClientDatasql.cs, ContactDataSql, etc)

    Several interfaces (IClientData.cs,IContactData.cs, etc)

    1 Class called DataFactory.cs
```

All the classes in the library are partial e.g.

```
Client.cs, Client.Generated.cs
ContactManager.cs, ContactManagerGenerated.cs   
BaseData.cs, Basedata.Generated.cs
Etc.
```

All this classes were generated with a code generator, this code generator was written by someone in my workplace.The approach used was "Data Base First",  Entity Framework was not used to do that.

My questions is:

How can I start to create my own code generator in order to generate that kind of classes?

Is there any tool to help me to do it?
Or should I write it from scratch?
What kind of topics should I start to read?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea if you start by reviewing exactly what Entity Framework is, and what it provides.

My favorite starting point when I have an EF question is often [msdn.microsoft.com/ef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ef).

In your specific case, EF supports a workflow called Database First where an existing database is used for the basis of the entities that will be used. There are a number of tools available that can take a database and generate entity classes from it. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj200620) is a basic example of how that's done.